# Python, BS and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to webscrape with javascript dynamic + bs + python and Ive read a lot of things to come up with this code where I try to scrape a price rendered with javascript on a famous website for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.nespresso.com/fr/fr/order/capsules/original/"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = "C:/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe")
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

soup.find("span", {'class':'ProductListElement__price'}).text
```

But I only have as a result '\xa0' which is the source value, not the javascript value and I don't know really what I did wrong ...

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the expense of a browser. The info is in a script tag so you can regex that out and handle with json library

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://www.nespresso.com/fr/fr/order/capsules/original/')
p = re.compile(r'window\.ui\.push\((.*ProductList.*)\)')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
products = {product['name']:product['price'] for product in data['configuration']['eCommerceData']['products']}
print(products)
```

Regex:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for this information, can you explain how did you find the script tag ? I suspected to be in it but couldn't find it by inspecting elements.

Comment: I pulled back the response with [jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/) which won't run javascript then searched the response for a product name /price off the actual webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to get the prices

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.nespresso.com/fr/fr/order/capsules/original/"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source

# Getting the prices using bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
prices = soup.select('.ProductListElement__price')
print([p.text for p in prices])

# Getting the prices using selenium 
prices =browser.find_elements_by_class_name("ProductListElement__price")
print([p.text for p in prices])
```

Comment: Oh thanks so the PhantomJS was the problem since the beginning ... shame on me.
Big thanks !